# Content Access Help

Tags: nodes, 7, users

Are there any modules for 7.x that will allow users to select whether content they create will be for authorized users only or anonymously viewable?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is usually best solved with a bit of indirection.

Have a look at the [Taxonomy Access](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) module. It allows to control access who can view content based on the assigned tags.

You can then add two tags, one for All and one for authenticated only, configured them and let your users chose which one they want for a node.

The advantage of this over e.g. a checkbox that allows to make it visible to all or authenticated only is that it is very easy to extend. For example, if you decide to add another role to your system, and want to limit access to only that role, it's as easy as adding another tag.